# Conditional *ngFor loop - Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to make a row of 4 different images from a list of images in Angular with the *ngFor loop. But what I am getting are rows of 4 and the same images.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let image of gallery; let i = index">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-s-6 col-4 col-l-3">
    <img (click)="openModal()" [src]="getSanitizeUrl(image)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-s-6 col-4 col-l-3">
    <img (click)="openModal()" [src]="getSanitizeUrl(image)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-s-6 col-4 col-l-3">
    <img (click)="openModal()" [src]="getSanitizeUrl(image)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-s-6 col-4 col-l-3">
    <img (click)="openModal()" [src]="getSanitizeUrl(image)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to solve this issue, but I chose to write it this way to try to help explain.

In the TypeScript file, you have the array of image names called `gallery`. You want them in groups of 4 for the display. So let's go ahead and create those groups in the TypeScript file in `ngOnInit`.

```
groupedGallery = [];

ngOnInit() {
    let group = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.gallery.length; i++) {
        if (group.length==4) {
            this.groupedGallery.push(group);
            group = [this.gallery[i]];
        } else {
            group.push(this.gallery[i]);
        }
    }
    if (group.length>0) {
        this.groupedGallery.push(group);
    }
}
```

Now we will use the new groups of arrays, `groupedGallery` to make the rows of images that you desire in the HTML. We will loop the groupedGallery using an `ng-container` since that won't create any HTML, it just controls the loop. Inside the container, we will create a row for each group. Inside the row, we will create a column for each image in that group.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groupedGallery">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let image of group">
            <img (click)="openModal()" [src]="getSanitizeUrl(image)" class="hover-shadow">
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

If you ever wanted to change how many images showed in a row, you can change the CSS classes in the HTML, and update this line of code in TypeScript: `if (group.length==4) {`

I hope this helps.

Comment: This would just create a row for each image... but what I need is a row with 4 images.

Comment: Sorry. Yes. Move the *ngFor to the column div. Updated

Comment: Now everything is under the same row? But I need each row to have 4 images..

Comment: @BlueScoreMan Check out the re-write. Maybe this can help.

Comment: group = [this.gallery[i]]; I'm assuming this passes a new array with whatever image is at index i?

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It would've indeed sovled my issue but I made a workaround with Flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Your class names are incorrect. I am not sure, whether col-l-* can be used. Need to cross check the documentation.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let image of gallery; let i = index">
     {{image}} <!-- Replace your image code here -->
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aprfqw

Comment: all the images are still under the same row... I need each row to have only 4 images..

Comment: If you check the stackblitz output, they are arranged in 4 per row https://prnt.sc/138t2oh . If not, possible options are you are

Comment: 1. responsiveness was not enabled. Kindly check your index.html has <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> tag.

Comment: 2. You are testing in a small screen dimension

Comment: 3. Somehow the default bootstrap classes are overridden. You need to check via inspect element. Right click, inspect element, and share the classes you see liike this https://prnt.sc/138t9qd

Answer (score 0):

you have different options. chunking the array before passing to *ngFor. having 2 *ngfor there and use slice pipe. the simplest one is using br tag after 4th item.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2lerho?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let image of gallery; let i = index">
  <br  *ngIf="i % 4 == 0"/> 
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-s-6 col-4 col-l-3">
    <img (click)="openModal()" [src]="getSanitizeUrl(image)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
</div>
```